# dotted lines in fieldset overlap with legend (CKEditor)

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, legend, fieldset

I am trying to create a fieldset with dotted lines but overlap in IE 8. I had no problems with Firefox and Chrome. The problem is with IE only. I tried some workarounds but nothing is working. If I set the lines to 1px and solid to any color I have no problems. Problem comes when I set border dotted. 
My css in CKEditor is;

```
editor.addCss(
          'fieldset' +
        '{' +
            'position: relative;' +
            'margin: 10px;' +
            'border: 1px dotted #00f;' + 

        '}'
        );

editor.addCss(
         '* + fieldset legend' +
        '{' +
            'position: absolute;' +
            'top: -10px;' +
            'left: 3px;' +
            'margin-bottom: 30px\9;' + 

        '}'
        );
```